# Envío XML usando SOAP - PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Buen día, necesito su ayuda para el envío de un XML a través de SOAP de acuerdo a instrucciones de mi proveedor

Problemas:

1. No me genera los namespaces completos (Parte superior xmlns:xsi y xmlns:xsd)
2. No me genera el tipo de variable para el arreglo fields (ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string")

Este es mi código y el XML que me genera

```
    $WebService = new SoapClient('https:urldeconsulta.asmx?wsdl', array( 'trace' => 1 ) );

    $datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][0] = array("Name"=>"id_cliente","Value"=>"123456789");
    $datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][1] = array("Name"=>"nombre_cliente","Value"=>"Daniel");
    $datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][2] = array("Name"=>"telefono_cliente","Value"=>"123456");

    $parametros = array(
        "ticketOfficeID" => 2259, 
        "amount" => 291944,
        "vatAmount" => 5444,
        "paymentID" => 9561,
        "paymentDescription" => PAGOS PSE,
        "referenceNumber1" => 10.10.10.244,
        "referenceNumber2" => NIT,
        "referenceNumber3" => 900000000,
        "serviceCode" => 5001,
        "email" => correocliente@gmail.com,
        "fields" => $datosCliente,
        "entity_url" => "http:urlRespuesta.php",
    );

    $Responce = $WebService->createTransactionPaymentHosting( $parametros );

    //Este es el XML que me arroja

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns1="http://www.achcolombia.com.co/PSEHostingWS">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
                <ns1:ticketOfficeID>2259</ns1:ticketOfficeID>
                <ns1:amount>291944</ns1:amount>
                <ns1:vatAmount>5444</ns1:vatAmount>
                <ns1:paymentID>9561</ns1:paymentID>
                <ns1:paymentDescription>PAGOS PSE</ns1:paymentDescription>
                <ns1:referenceNumber1>10.10.10.244</ns1:referenceNumber1>
                <ns1:referenceNumber2>NIT</ns1:referenceNumber2>
                <ns1:referenceNumber3>900000000</ns1:referenceNumber3>
                <ns1:serviceCode>5001</ns1:serviceCode>
                <ns1:email>correocliente@gmail.com</ns1:email>
                <ns1:fields>
                    <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                        <ns1:Name>id_cliente</ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:Value>123456789</ns1:Value>
                    </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                        <ns1:Name>nombre_cliente</ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:Value>Daniel</ns1:Value>
                    </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                        <ns1:Name>telefono_cliente</ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:Value>123456</ns1:Value>
                    </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                </ns1:fields>
                <ns1:entity_url>http:urlRespuesta.php</ns1:entity_url>
            </ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Este es el XML que debo enviar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.achcolombia.com.co/PSEHostingWS">
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
            <ns1:ticketOfficeID>2259</ns1:ticketOfficeID>
            <ns1:amount>291944</ns1:amount>
            <ns1:vatAmount>5444</ns1:vatAmount>
            <ns1:paymentID>9561</ns1:paymentID>
            <ns1:paymentDescription>PAGOS PSE</ns1:paymentDescription>
            <ns1:referenceNumber1>10.10.10.244</ns1:referenceNumber1>
            <ns1:referenceNumber2>NIT</ns1:referenceNumber2>
            <ns1:referenceNumber3>900000000</ns1:referenceNumber3>
            <ns1:serviceCode>5001</ns1:serviceCode>
            <ns1:email>correocliente@gmail.com</ns1:email>
            <ns1:fields>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>id_cliente</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123456789</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>nombre_cliente</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Daniel</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
                <ns1:PSEHostingField>
                    <ns1:Name>telefono_cliente</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123456</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:PSEHostingField>
            </ns1:fields>
            <ns1:entity_url>http:urlRespuesta.php</ns1:entity_url>
        </ns1:createTransactionPaymentHosting>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: ¿Te está generando algún error la llamada? Desde mi punto de vista, los namespaces que no está generando en el Soap Envelope no se necesitan en el mensaje.
De hecho esos namespaces están relacionados con la definición del esquema del servicio (seguramente los vas a ver en el contenido del contrato wsdl). No se van en el mensaje.
Tal cual está armado tu mensaje XML no debería tener problemas en la invocación del servicio.

Comment: Javier, gracias por responder, si me esta generando el siguiente error: 

Type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' in Assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Según me indica el proveedor es por los argumentos que me faltan en el XML

Comment: Hay algunas herramientas que te permiten probar los servicios y entre otras cosas te ayudan a descubrir si se trata de un problema de cliente o del servidor. Una de las que utilizo es SOAPUI y me ha resultado de utilidad. 
¿Puedes incluir el contenido del contrato (.wsdl) del servicio para poder verificar si realmente se trata de un problema del formato del mensaje (normalmente se debe a otra cosa)...

Comment: La herramienta que indicas ya la estoy usando, me di cuenta que el problema esta en el arreglo del campo Fields, si paso este parámetro en blanco da respuesta, según validación con el proveedor el por lo que me falta esto No me genera los namespaces completos (Parte superior xmlns:xsi y xmlns:xsd)
No me genera el tipo de variable para el arreglo fields (ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución en otra fuente, la publico por si le sirve a alguién

Agregue SoapVar object

```
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][0] = array("Name"=>"id_cliente","Value"=>new SoapVar("123456789", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][1] = array("Name"=>"nombre_cliente","Value"=>new SoapVar("Daniel", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
$datosCliente["PSEHostingField"][2] = array("Name"=>"telefono_cliente","Value"=>new SoapVar("123456", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
```